# Locus involving a variable triangle

Tags: triangles, locus

The base BC of a variable triangle ABC is fixed, and the sum AB+AC is constant. The line DP drawn through the midpoint D of BC parallel to AB meets the line CP at P where CP is a line parallel to the angle bisector of A passing through C. Prove that the locus of P is a circle with D for center.

From the given condition that AB+AC is constant, it is clear that the locus of A must be an ellipse. However constructing an ellipse is not easy and I want to know  how to approach the problem without needing to do that.
(I don't need a full solution, just a clue)

Comment: Addressing got concern that "consturcting an ellipse is not easy": You don't need to draw an accurate diagram to get started. Just draw a good enough approximation of case(s). $\quad$ Hint: If ABC is an isosceles triangle (There are 2 possibilities), then where is $P$? Hence, (assuming the result is true), what is the circle (radius and center) that is the locus of $P$? Working with that knowledge, how can we prove the statement?

Comment: I do get your point and infact I did construct the point P by randomly considering a triangle ABC but how do we prove that the locus is the circle we are talking about since it is what is asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the figure:

[image]

Show that $DE = 0.5AB$ and $EC = 0.5AC$ using the [converse of the mid point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_theorem_(triangle)#:%7E:text=the%20same%20ratio.-,The%20converse,-of%20the%20theorem).
Next, find $\angle EPC$ in terms of $x$ and $\angle B$ (use the parallel lines). Then find $\angle ECP$ and show that the two are equal. This implies $0.5AC = EC = EP$. So, $DP = DE+EP = 0.5AB+0.5AC = 0.5(AB+AC)$ which is a constant. 
$D$ is a fixed point, while $P$ is a variable point and $DP$ is constant. The locus of a point which has a fixed distance from a fixed point is a circle.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is correct.
Show that DE=0.5AB
and EC=0.5AC
using the converse of the mid point theorem.
Next, find ∠EPC
in terms of x
and ∠B
(use the parallel lines). Then find ∠ECP
and show that the two are equal. This implies 0.5AC=EC=EP
. So, DP=DE+EP=0.5AB+0.5AC=0.5(AB+AC)
which is a constant.
D
is a fixed point, while P
is a variable point and DP
is constant. The locus of a point which has a fixed distance from a fixed point is a circle.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).